# How to get a dojo instance that was instantiated declaratively?

Tags: javascript, grails, dojo

I have the following in my grails project:

```
               <div dojoType="dojo.dnd.Source" id="available" class="container" accept="avail,select"  onMouseUp="selectChange" jsId="gradesSource"
                style="overflow:scroll;">
               <g:each status="i" var="grade" in="${chooseList}">
                  <div id="grade_${grade}" class="dojoDndItem" dndType="avail">${grade}</div>
               </g:each>
               </div>
```

How do I get a reference to that dojo.dnd.Source object from a javascript function?

Is there a shortcut method? I noticed dojo.byId("avilable") would get me the  DOM object, but I need to access functions in the dojo.dnd.Source

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use jsId="available" to create an identifier in the global scope.

Comment: How do I use it from my javascript function?

Comment: just access it as a global variable `available` or whatever you set jsId equal to.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew pointed out, you can use `jsId="someVariableName"`, which makes the dijit widget available under the global scope under the variable name "someVariableName".  I think that method may be deprecated though.

What you're probably looking for is using `dijit.byId('available');`  the dijit.byId function differs from dojo.byId in that dijit.byId looks for widgets by Id whereas dojo.byId just return's DOM Nodes.